# Do Crooks run away more if you have nothing to steal?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

The description for the Crook enemy in the Monster List says:

> When a Crook flees without stealing anything, it's because they've abandoned the idea of Mario carrying anything of value.

I've often seen Crooks run away on the first turn of a battle. Is the Monster List description just flavor text, or will Crooks actually run away more often if I don't have a lot of money or valuable items worth stealing?

[image: Monster List page for Crook]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is just flavor text

I'm not basing this answer upon anything in the code; just a ton of experience playing this game and the original.

Crooks and their late-game counterparts, Sackits, probably run from battle 50% of the time.

I saw this just last night when I revisited Star Hill to check on the post-game content. I had a ton of end game items, well over 1,500 coins (suffice to say I tip always tip in Marrymore just to dump this money somewhere), ample frog coins as well.

If a Sackit ran into me while exploring, they were usually just a little faster than me if Geno's not in the party. About half the time, their 1st turn was to run away. The other half of the time they hit for pathetic damage and then wish they ran away as a Lazy Shell goes through their teeth.